# Meteor.call in client doesn't wait when the called method has another call inside

Tags: meteor, async-await

I am following what I've read around being the standard way to use Meteor.call but it's behaving strangely in this scenario:

Client:

```
Template.sometemplate.events({
    'submit .somebutton'(event){
         ...
         Meteor.call('stuff.someMethod', param1, function (err, res){
              console.log(err);
              console.log(res);
         };
    }
})
```

Server /api/stuff.js:

```
Meteor.methods({
    'stuff.someMethod'(param1){
         ...
         Meteor.call('otherstuff.someOtherMethod', param1, function(err, res){
                  if(err){ throw new Meteor.Error(400,'wrong things');}
                  if(res) { return 'ok';}
             }
         );
    }
})
```

Server /api/otherstuff.js:

```
Meteor.methods({
    'otherstuff.someOtherMethod'(param1){
         ...
         return OtherStuff.findOne(query);
    }
})
```

On the client side I click and immediately see the console.log for both err and res as undefined. Whereas in other parts of the application when the client calls a server method, which is not calling another method, the client waits for the answer before executing the asynch callback.

There must be something wrong in how I use the Meteor.call inside a server method calling another server method. The scenario is that for instance I want to insert a document and while doing so I want to check some values in order to link it to other documents from other collections.

Thank you very much,
T.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Sync call on the server

Using [Meteor.call](https://docs.meteor.com/api/methods.html#Meteor-call) on the server does not require a callback, unless you really want to work async on the server side.

> If you do not pass a callback on the server, the method invocation
>   will block until the method is complete. It will eventually return the
>   return value of the method, or it will throw an exception if the
>   method threw an exception. (Possibly mapped to 500 Server Error if the
>   exception happened remotely and it was not a Meteor.Error exception.)

Instead of passing a callback you would either return the result

```js
return Meteor.call(...)
```

or assign it to a variable that is used for further processing.

```js
const retVal = Meteor.call(...)
```

## Better way: Externalize shared code

If two meteor methods rely on the same code (e.g. one is calling the other) you should extract this code into a shared function. This makes testing and tracing errors also easier.

**server/api/common.js**

```js
export const sharedFunction = function(param1) {
    // ... do somethin
    return OtherStuff.findOne(query); 
}
```

**server/api/stuff.js:**

```js
import { sharedFunction } from './common.js';

Meteor.methods({
    'stuff.someMethod'(param1){
         // ...
         const temp = sharedFunction(param1);
         // ...
         return result; // or temp if this should be returned to client
    }
})
```

**server/api/otherstuff.js**

```js
import { sharedFunction } from './common.js';

Meteor.methods({
    'otherstuff.someOtherMethod'(param1){
         return sharedFunction(param1);
    }
});
```

Using the `sharedFunction` follows the concepts of [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) and [Single Point of Failure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_point_of_failure).

Comment: Thanks, I just followed your suggestion: const retVal = Meteor.call(param1); and wrapped it into a try catch (lets make it work, then I'll make it nice). And the client now waits for the response. Thanks also for the shared approach, makes sense indeed.